# What does the escape sequence """ does in python 3.7.0

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python from the book LP3THW by Zed Shaw. In 'Exercise 10. What Was That?' chapter the code goes like this:

```
1 tabby_cat = "\tI'm tabbed in."
2 persian_cat = "I'm split\non a line."
3 backslash_cat = "I'm \\ a \\ cat."
4
5 fat_cat = """
6 I'll do a list:
7 \t* Cat food
8 \t* Fishies
9 \t* Catnip\n\t* Grass
10 """
11
12 print(tabby_cat)
13 print(persian_cat)
14 print(backslash_cat)
15 print(fat_cat)
```

and the o/p is this:

```
        I'm tabbed in.
I'm split
on a line.
I'm \ a \ cat .

I'll do a list:
        * Cat food
        * Fishies
        * Catnip
        * Grass
```

The **three double quotes """** start on **line 5** and end at **line 10**. What does they do. Please help.

Comment: Triple quotes are string delineators that can span multiple lines. Does the book you're reading really not tell you what they are?

Comment: What is the impact of """ on the o/p. I didn't get that.

Answer (score 0):

Using `"""` allows for the string to be split over several lines and outputed as it is shown in the text editor. When coding in python you normally use `"string"`, however if you attempted to write

```
print("This will go
on to the next line")
```

You will recieve an error because of the line break. The use of `"""string"""` stops this so:

```
print("""This will go
on to the next line""")
```

will run sucessfuly with no errors but the line break will be preserved generating the output:

```
This will go
on to the next line
```

Comment: Thank's Elephant, your answer is helpful to understand the concept